# How to change the default docker directory (/var/lib/docker) by docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm using docker-machine for simple deploying docker containers to remote host. But sometimes I get memory overflow errors.  I don't have enough space in /var/lib/docker.  How could i change default docker folder (/var/lib/docker to /home/my/dir) by docker-machine?

I use the following command:

docker-machine create --driver "generic"  --generic-ssh-user "$USER"  --generic-ip-address "$HOST_IP" "$MACHINE_NAME"

Could I put some parameter like this "--data-root=/home/my/dir"?

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant by change the default docker folder. Did you mean the mount point in your host machine or the path set in docker config inside the VM?

Comment: I mean the folder that will be created in remote host (during installation of docker on the remote host).

Answer (score 1):

Setting up custom parameters for the `dockerd` isn't available using `docker-machine`, as you can see in the [VirtualBox implementation](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/drivers/virtualbox/virtualbox.go#L299) for example.

But that doesn't mean that it can't be done. The `docker-machine` project relies on [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) and [it's parameters can be changed using a file](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#docker-daemon-options). But that would depend on the virtualization software more than on the `docker-machine` application itself.